# Copy row based on today's date and paste values on a specific sheet and trigger by today's time

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy, row

I need help with copying a row based on today's date and paste the value on specific sheet.
It will be better if I can copy a week (7 days, 7 rows) and paste the value.
And trigger based on that week's Friday 2359Hours.
For example, today = 20 Nov 2020. 7 days = (14 Nov 2020 to 20 Nov 2020).
The Google Sheet is filled with data from Column A(date) to Z(Last Modified).
I need the 7 rows of data to shows the changes made for that week.

Please assist me. Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain how javascript is related to your questions? Google sheet appears to be more relevant, if I am following your question correctly.

Comment: Yes. I am using Google Sheet for data collection. I was told that Google Sheet uses Javascript.

Comment: @Bernard it's more accurate to say Google Sheets uses Google Apps Script, which is JavaScript-based. Can you share a opy of your sheet to help illustrate what you mean?